# How do I forward declare an object in a class? (C++)

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

So basically, I have a global class and a player class. They are both defined in their ObjPlayer.h/ObjPlayer.cpp and same for the global. But how do I forward declare an instance of ObjPlayer within ObjGlobal?

Here is what I have: (Defining the constructor, the class deceleration is elsewhere.)

```
//Create all the objects
GlobalClass::GlobalClass(void)
{
    //Create a player for testing
    ObjPlayer oPlayer(4, 8);
}
```

But since it's in the contructor, I don't think I can access the class as is in the main function.

```
int main()
{
    GlobalClass oGlobal();
    oGlobal.oPlayer.showVars(); //Doesn't work...

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

(I know I'm not supposed to use system, it's just for debugging.)

I'm quite confused, and I'm not sure how to solve this. (I'm pretty noobish with C++, my main language is GML...)

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "forward declaring" an object within a class? It doesn't make much sense in C++.

Comment: You need to make oPlayer a member of GlobalClass. Either a public one, or a private with a getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating and destroying a local variable within the constructor, not a class member. Once the constructor has finished, it no longer exists, so there's no way to access it from outside.

A class member needs to be declared in the class:

```
class GlobalClass {
    //...
    ObjPlayer oPlayer;
    //...
};
```

which can be initialised by the constructor:

```
GlobalClass::GlobalClass() : oPlayer(4,8) {}
```

and (if public) accessed as you want:

```
GlobalClass oGlobal;   // no (), that would declare a function
oGlobal.oPlayer.showVars();
```

Answer (score -1):

in the objGlobal head file, before the class declerations add:

```
class oPlayer;
```